# How to develop ActionBar to have logo in the center and two action items on sides?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am developing android app in that i have requirement to develop action bar like 
action bar to have logo in the center and two action items on sides like this?

[image]

I done above requirement using custom action bar but i got output like following.

[image]

I don't know how to put the separator line to action bar menu so following is the 
my code of
custom action bar

abc.java

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.navigation_back);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
   // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

custom_action_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_desired_background" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/file"
        android:icon="@drawable/verticle_action_menu"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@null">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
                android:onClick="Refresh"
                android:title="@string/refresh"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_home"
                android:onClick="Home"
                android:title="@string/home"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_about"
                android:onClick="About"
                android:title="@string/about"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:title="@string/logout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

please anybody having another way to do this so please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to the `TextView` and then you got the text at the center.